# Not receiving JSONP callback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonp

I am following the sample code/tutorial for ASP.NET MVC and JSONP blog post: http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-EnablingJSONPcallsonASPNETMVC.aspx

I have taken the code sample and have modified it for my own consumption.

When I hit the page, it fires off my controller's action but the `$.getJSON(call, function (rsp)..` is not firing at all.

**Controller action**

```
[JsonpFilter]
public JsonpResult GetMyObjects(int id)
{
    List<MyObject> list = MyDAO.GetMyObjects(id);

    return new JsonpResult
        {
            Data = list,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
}
```

**HTML Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var url = "http://localhost/MySite.ContentDelivery/MyController/GetMyObjects/?";


            function getObjects() {
                //
                // build the URL
                //
                debugger;
                var call = url + "id=48&jsoncallback=?";

                //
                // make the ajax call
                //
                $.getJSON(call, function (rsp) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(rsp);
                    if (rsp.stat != "ok") {
                        //
                        // something went wrong!
                        //
                        $("#myDiv").append(
                            "<label style=\"background-color:red;color:white;padding: 25px;\">Whoops!  It didn't work!" +
                            "  This is embarrassing!  Here's what the system had to " +
                            " say about this - " + rsp.message + "</label>");
                    }
                    else {
                        //
                        // build the html
                        //
                        var html = "";
                        $.each(rsp.list.myObject, function () {
                            var obj = this;
                            html += "<span" + obj.Name + "</span> <br />";
                        });

                        //
                        // append this to the div
                        //
                        $("#myDiv").append(html);
                    }
                });
            }

            //
            // get the offers
            //
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('go..');
                $(getOobjects);
            });
    </script>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**tl;dr** why is my `getJson()` not firing while my `getObjects()` fires and executes the MVC controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
var call = url + "id=48&jsoncallback=?";
```

with:

```
var call = url + "id=48&callback=?";
```

The custom `JsonpResult` you are using relies on a query string parameter called `callback` and not `jsoncallback`:

```
Callback = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["callback"];
```

Also you have decorated your controller action with a `[JsonpFilter]` attribute and returning a `JsonpResult`. As explained in the article you must have read you should choose one:

```
[JsonpFilter]
public ActionResult GetMyObjects(int id)
{
    List<MyObject> list = MyDAO.GetMyObjects(id);

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

or the other:

```
public ActionResult GetMyObjects(int id)
{
    List<MyObject> list = MyDAO.GetMyObjects(id);

    return new JsonpResult
    {
        Data = list,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

but do not mix the two.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me. Should I create a new question now for the following issue - The `rsp` is empty when the `.getJson()` exectutes i.e. it doesn't contain a list.

Comment: Yes, you could create a new question. But don't forget to show the important code (i.e. the `MyObject` model that your contorller action is returning and the `MyDAO.GetMyObjects` method implementation).

Comment: Thanks Darin, I have just created the new question with the actual original code and no obfuscated properties etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054200/jsonp-callback-response-data-is-null